# Tengo problemas con un error el cual no entiendo por que aparece

Tags: java, string, char

Estoy realizando un código el cual sirve para que aparezca una cadena de manera vertical utilizando el ciclo `while`. Ya terminé el código, pero a lo último de la ejecución me marca un error el cual no entiendo por que aparece. El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ciclos {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String N;

        System.out.print("Digite una palabra: ");
        N = kboard.nextLine();

        int n = (N.length()-N.length())-1;
        int nm = N.length();

        System.out.println("\n Asi se ve '" + N + "' en vertical:");

        while (n<=nm) {
           n++;
           char i = N.charAt(n);
           System.out.println(i);
        }
   }
}
```

El problema que me lanza es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1515)
        at Ciclos.main(Ciclos.java:20)
```

Lo que me parece más raro es que a la hora de eliminar la línea `char i = N.charAt(n);` ya no me aparece el error, pero ya no me da el resultado que necesito.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ciclos {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String N;

        System.out.print("Digite una palabra: ");
        N = kboard.nextLine();

        int n = (N.length()-N.length())-1;
        int nm = N.length();

        System.out.println("\n Asi se ve '" + N + "' en vertical:");

        while (n<=nm) {
           n++;
           System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Si alguien sabe que podría hacer le pido que deje su comentario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque NetoXD99 ya te ha ofrecido la solución, no ha explicado exactamente cuál era tu problema original.

Me temo que si quieres dedicarte a esto vas a tener que aprender algo de inglés, ya que la mayoría de ejemplos, artículos, documentación y foros (quitando éste) están en ese idioma. Y aunque a medida que vayas aumentado la complejidad de tu código te irás encontrando excepciones prácticamente ilegibles incluso si eres inglés nativo, en este caso tanto la excepción como el mensaje están bastante claros:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7

Esta excepción se produce cuando intentas acceder a una posición que no existe dentro de una cadena de caracteres, dicha posición está fuera del rango permitido (index out of range), el índice está fuera de los límites (index out of bounds). Seguramente para que te aparezca ese número 7 hayas introducido una palabra de 7 letras, con lo cual las posiciones válidas van de la 0 a la 6, tal y como están numeradas las posiciones en Java.

Cualquier número entero que introduzcas fuera de ese rango [0..6] al invocar `charAt` producirá esa excepción: -45, -4, 7, 23, 7812, ...

Si consultas el [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html#StringIndexOutOfBoundsException--) para ese tipo de excepción encontrarás la misma explicación mencionando explícitamente el método `charAt`:

> public class StringIndexOutOfBoundsException extends
> IndexOutOfBoundsException
>  Thrown by String methods to indicate that an
> index is either negative or greater than the size of the string. For
> some methods such as the charAt method, this exception also is thrown
> when the index is equal to the size of the string.

Dicho esto, permite que te ofrezca algunas mejoras en tu código. Por favor, usa nombres para tus variables que tengan significado y que sigan las convenciones universales del lenguaje de programación que uses. Esto aumentará la legibilidad del código para cualquiera que intente entenderlo.

Ese cualquiera puede ser un compañero que tenga que modificar tu código o tú mismo pasados unos meses, de forma que ya no recuerdes porqué programaste el código de esa forma.

¿A qué me refiero con "que tengan significado"? N, n, nm no significan nada y además la primera no sigue las convenciones de Java de que las variables no deben empezar por mayúsculas (para diferenciarlas claramente de las constantes, cuyo nombre se escriben siempre con todas las letras mayúsculas)
Encima no queda claro exactamente qué quieres almacenar en n, cuyo valor siempre será -1. ¿Porqué usar esa extraña operación en lugar de poner -1 directamente? ¿Y para qué necesitas nm si puedes usar directamente la longitud de la palabra leída?

También relacionado con el significado, entiendo que pongas kboard pero un objeto Scanner no representa un teclado. Si yo pulso Ctrl o Alt, dicho objeto no hace nada. Normalmente para ese tipo de objetos se usa simplemente sc.

Por último, ¿porqué importas el paquete `javax.swing.*` si no usas ninguna de sus clases? Supongo que estarás usando algún IDE para tus prácticas como Eclipse o IntelliJ. Dicho IDE te marcará situaciones anómalas como esa y te ofrecerá una manera rápida de corregirlas. En este caso, eliminando esa línea.

Aplicando todas estas sugerencias, el código quedaría así

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestVertical {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Digite una palabra: ");
        String palabraLeida = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\n Así se ve '" + palabraLeida + "' en vertical:");
        int indice = 0;
        while (indice < palabraLeida.length()) {
           char letra = palabraLeida.charAt(indice);
           System.out.println(letra);
           indice++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Al introducir una palabra de siete letras, se obtendría esta salida

[image: Salida obtenida]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la inicializacion de las variables n y nm. así que se mueve el incremento al final del bucle while para que asegures de que se incremente después de imprimir el caractér.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ciclos {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String N;

        System.out.print("Digite una palabra: ");
        N = kboard.nextLine();

        int n = 0;
        int nm = N.length();

        System.out.println("\nAsí se ve '" + N + "' en vertical:");

        while (n < nm) {
            char i = N.charAt(n);
            System.out.println(i);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```